# How to use a Javascript variable, out side the script tag in the image tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know - how we can use this Javascript variable1(user_email) , out side the script tag in the image tag(EMAILID).

Javascript code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ***user_email = " ***@Customer.Email.Value@@*** "; [Variable 1]
    .
    .
    .
</script>
```

Need to pass variable 1 to the following img tag:

```
<img src="https://something.aspx?c=12345&e= ***EMAILID*** " /> [Variable 2]
```

Note: Image tag should not be used inside a javascript.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: `</blink>`? really? :-P what decade r u in? ^_^

Comment: what century even ? (queue someone saying blink tag was not available until 2002 or something)

Comment: although the solution is quite straightforward ask yourself: If user has JS disabled you are **not** making feature (image) unavailable but **sort-of-available** which could be catastrophic in some more sensitive cases...

Answer (score 2):

LOL I can see that `</blink>` attracted much attention!

Anyhow, you can't do the way you want. You need to access `IMG` element using `getElementById` and set the whole `src` once you have `user_email`:

```
document.getElementById('my_image').src = "....";
```

Comment: <img src="" id="myimage" />
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var user_email = "someone@gmail.com";
          var img_src = " " + user_email;
          document.getElementById("myimage").setAttribute("src",img_src);
        </script>

Comment: In that case also we need to use script tag rite?